# My picklist is not filling correctly (jquery-ui picklist + angularjs filling)

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui

I am using: https://code.google.com/archive/p/jquery-ui-picklist/.

I understand I should not mix both technologies, but there's not too much angularjs picklist and I implemented the one from jquery-ui.

It is opening the picklist in my modal, but using ng-repeat and does not give any errors and does not work.

It used to work on another picklist I was using (another template).

What could the problem be?

[image]

```js
angular.module('BoxApp').controller("CadastroCertificado", function($scope, $http) {

 $scope.clientes = {};
 $scope.listaEmpresas = [];
 
 $scope.iniciar = function() {
  $http.get(urlRestServer + '/cadastrocertificado').success(function(response) {
   $scope.clientes = response;
   
  });
 };

 $scope.iniciar(); 
 
 /**
  * Trabalhando o componente picklist
  */
    $scope.clientes2 = [];     
 $scope.atribuirUm = function(index, c) {
  var cliente = {};
  cliente.idCliente = c.idCliente;
  cliente.razaoSocial = c.razaoSocial;
     $scope.clientes2.push(cliente);
     $scope.clientes.splice(index, 1);
 };
 $scope.limparUm = function(index, c2) {
     $scope.clientes2.splice(index, 1);
     $scope.clientes.push(c2);     
 };
 
 /**
  * Trecho para validar o form ao submeter.
  */
 $scope.submitted = false;
 $scope.submitForm = function(form, clientes2) {  
  $scope.listaEmpresas = $scope.clientes2;
  $scope.submitted = true;
  if (form.$valid) {   
   $scope.cadastraCertificado();
  }
 }; 

 /**
  * Requisição POST (ajax)
  */
 $scope.cadastraCertificado = function() {
  
  var dados = {
    urlCertificado : $scope.certificadoIncluirAlterar.urlCertificado,
    strDataValidadeCertificado : $scope.certificadoIncluirAlterar.strDataValidadeCertificado.toString(),
    senhaCertificado : $scope.certificadoIncluirAlterar.senhaCertificado,
    listaEmpresas : $scope.listaEmpresas    
  };
  
  $http.post(urlRestServer + '/cadastrocertificado/salvarCertificado', dados).then(function(response) {
   
  }, function(response) { 
   $scope.sucesso();
  });
 }; 
 
 $scope.sucesso = function() {
  $scope.closeModal();
  $scope.iniciar();  
 };
 
 $scope.closeModal = function() {
  $('#myModal').modal('hide');
 };

});
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-3">Empresas:</label>
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <select id="foobar" name="foobar" multiple="multiple">                                             
              <option ng-repeat="c in clientes" value="{{c.idCliente}}" ng-click="atribuirUm($index, c)">{{c.razaoSocial}}</option>
              <option selected ng-repeat="c2 in clientes2" value="{{c2.idCliente}}" ng-click="limparUm($index, c2)">{{c2.razaoSocial}}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I made by myself a picklist and applied css classes to it.

Better than mixing Jquery with AngularJS, it was only giving me headaches and errors.